# how would the 3-tier architecture be applied in a Rich Internet Application (Flash/Flex)?

Tags: .net, apache-flex, flash, air

how would the 3-tier architecture be applied in a Rich Internet Application?

I thougt that flex was presentation, .net web services where busines and informix was data. But then when I started I feel that I must be wrong.

thanks.

Comment: dear God, my engrish/grammar is horrible today, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of MVC, my largish Flex application is using dual MVC layers. The server (ruby on rails) is using MVC where the layers are fairly straightforward since rails is an MVC architecture by default. On the flex client we also have an MVC using PureMVC where the model is the view from rails, the view is the rendered elements, and the controller is the stuff in the middle.

Some people prefer to have a more direct connection to the server and use flex as an extension of the server view with next to no business logic, but this becomes impractical in many more complicated cases where you need more elegant client-side data caching.